# How do i edit a copy of a string without changing the original string

Tags: c, string

I am trying to reverse a string i.e. if the original string is 12345 I want to output 54321. I thought it would be good to copy the original string and edit the copy, but inside the for loop (where I try to swap the elements; I've put a marker "HERE"), both the original string and the copy of the string get edited. Could someone explain to me why that's happening? Thanks

```
char* reverseTheNumber (char* originalNumber){
    int lengthOfInputString = (strlen( originalNumber) - 1);
    char* copyOfOriginalNumber = originalNumber;
    
    int replacementIndex = lengthOfInputString; //index of original input to be swapped

    for (int i = 0; i <= (lengthOfInputString); i++){
        
        //swap the character; 1st for last, 2nd for 2ndlast, etc
        copyOfOriginalNumber[i] = originalNumber[replacementIndex];  //HERE

        replacementIndex -= 1;
    }

    return copyOfOriginalNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's *extremely* important to remember that this does **not** make a copy:

```
char* copyOfOriginalNumber = originalNumber;
```

This copies *the pointer* and does not touch the string data.

What you want is:

```
char* copyOfOriginalNumber = strdup(originalNumber);
```

Don't forget that there is a responsibility to eventually `free()` this copy.